# NATS-Streaming-Server <1ms latency

Tags: nats.io, nats-streaming-server

Is it possible to setup a nats-streaming-server cluster with a put-get latency < 1ms?

I created a 3 node cluster (all residing on the same server), using file storage.

eg,

```
# NATS specific configuration
port: 4222
cluster {
  listen: 127.0.0.1:6222
  routes: ["nats://127.0.0.1:6223", "nats://127.0.0.1:6224"]
}

# NATS Streaming specific configuration
streaming {
  id: test-cluster
  store: file
  dir: /srv/nats/store_a
  cluster {
    node_id: "a"
    peers: ["b", "c"]
  }
}
```

It is taking 2-3ms per message from async-publish to subscribe callback.

Any other ways to speed it up with file storage?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same on a MacbookPro and the latency is around 767 micro seconds, if you exclude the first message in which case the channel is being created.

You could get even better if all streaming servers were to connect to single central NATS Server since that would remove hop between NATS Servers.